# Create toomany AdView is it make account Suspension

Tags: android, admob

I am showing adview inside gridview, in code for 10 item create 1 adview below (now i have 36 item so there are 3 adview inside gridview)

In **debug** Mode I noticed at every scroll event, **getView** method inside Adapter is always executing.

That mean It is create too many adView all time.
is that normal ??

Before publishing the application I would like to make sure It will not cause any problem with admob policy when using real ads

Answer (score 1):

Calling getView method continously will not cause any problems, however you have to be careful that only one ad is visible on the screen at any point of time.

So you should not have two ads visible inside your recycler view to the user as it will cause policy violation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can call as many ads as you want in the recycler view without any policy violation just that, you should not have more than one ad in the visible screen area